# Is there a subring that has a different identity element from the original ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(S,+,.)$ be some ring.

Is there a subring of $(S,+,.)$ that has a different identity element from the identity element in $(S,+,.)$?

I am new to ring theory so please let answers simple.

Comment: This depends on your definition of "(sub)ring" and what $S$ is.

Answer (score 2):

Take rings $R,S$ and look at the cartesian product $R \times S$ with componentwise addition and multiplication. The subsets $R \times \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \times S$ should do it if I'm not mistaken.

Edit: Of course, this depends on the definition of subring. Sometimes you call $S \subseteq R$ a subring if $1 \in S$ (and the rest of the ring axioms).

Answer (score 2):

$2\Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z} \subset \Bbb{Z}/10\Bbb{Z}$.  Can you figure out the multiplicative identity of the subring?  Can you generalize this?

Answer (score 1):

$ 2\mathbb Z_{10}\subset\mathbb Z_{10}$ has identity $6$.

With functions: $\{f\in L^\infty [0,1]:\ f|_{[1/2,1]}=0\}\subset L^\infty[0,1] $, with identity $1_{[0,1/2)} $.

With matrices:
$$
\left\{\begin {bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&0\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&0\\0&0&0\end {bmatrix}:\ a_{kj}\subset S\right\}\subset M_3 (S).$$

With direct sums: if $R,S $ are rings, then $R\oplus0\subset R\oplus S $ with identity $1_R\oplus 0_S $.

Comment: I wish I understood your answer, but I just started studying ring theory and  abstract algebra. So my knowledge is very limited. But is seem If I Understand you correctly, there is a subring that has a different identity element from the original ring. Is that right?