# Identity element of a subring is the same as the identity element of the ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am studying the first chapter of "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by M. F. Atiyah and I. G. MacDonald. The book defined a subring as follows:

A subset $S$ of a ring $A$ is a subring of $A$ if $S$ is closed under addition and multiplication and contains the identity element of $A.$

I want to prove that if $S$ has identity $1_S$ then $1_S = 1_A,$ I do not know how to prove this, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Do you know that the identity is unique?

Comment: Well,  don't we have $1_S=1_S\cdot 1_A=1_A$?

Comment: Yeah @paulblartmathcop I know that the identity is unique

Comment: @pipe oh is this the proof? but I have seen here questions like this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616674/is-there-a-subring-that-has-a-different-identity-element-from-the-original-ring so I got confused

Comment: I think it'll work,  with your definition.   The linked examples don't contain $1_A$.

Comment: You already have asked a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4529908/proving-that-there-is-only-one-identity-element-in-a-commutative-ring-with-the-p).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ring can't have two identities,  since $1_1=1_1\cdot 1_2=1_2$.

Thus your definition,  where the subring includes the identity from the parent ring,  precludes the linked counterexamples.